# Names on searchbar, added by checkbox

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

```html
 <ion-header no-border style="border-bottom: 1px solid #EDEDED;">
  <ion-navbar  no-border-bottom>
    <ion-title>
      Nova Mensagem
    </ion-title>
     <ion-buttons end>
      <button  ion-button icon-only>
        <span style="color:#5D5A56">Seguinte</span>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content class="contentbg">



    <div style="padding:15px;background-color:white;" class="customborder2">
    <span style="font-size:16px;color:#5D5A56;margin-right:5px;margin-top:10px">Para:</span>

    <ion-chip *ngFor="let lista of selecionados; let i = index"  #chip1 style="background-color:#F0F0F0;color:#5D5A56;margin-right:5px">
  <ion-label>{{lista}}</ion-label>
  <button ion-button clear (click)="delete(chip1, listaIds[i], lista, check[i])">
    <ion-icon name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-chip>


</div>

<div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #F3F3F3;background-color:white">
  <ion-searchbar mode="md"
  [(ngModel)]="searchQuery"
  [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel"
  placeholder="Pesquisar utilizadores"
  (ionInput)="onInput($event)"
  (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)"> 
    </ion-searchbar>
    </div>

 <ion-label style="margin-left:15px;margin-top:30px;">
          <span class="strong" style="text-transform:uppercase;font-size:13px;color:#999999">{{titulo}}</span>
        </ion-label>

  <ion-list>

  <ion-item  *ngFor="let sugestao of sugeridos"  class="customborder customborder2 animacao" >
    <ion-label>
      <ion-avatar style="float:left">
          <div style="border-radius:50%;width:40px;height:40px;background-position:center;background-size:cover" [style.background-image]="'url(http://bacotaco.web.ua.pt/img/' + sugestao.foto + ')'"></div>
        </ion-avatar>
        <div style="float:left;position:relative;top:3px;left:10px">
          <div style="text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow: hidden;"><p style="font-size:16px;color:black">{{sugestao.nomeC}}</p></div>
          <p class="sub" style="color:#AAAAAA;font-size:14px;">{{sugestao.tipo}}</p>
          </div>
    </ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox item-right color="tint"  (click)="selecionado(sugestao.id, sugestao.nome, sugestao.index)"  [(ngModel)]="sugestao.selecionado"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>

  

</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

You can select people via a list created from a database, by searching.

_

The structure is the following:

*A div with "To:", where the names are added after (To: Mike e.g.);*

*The search bar;*

*An ion-list with the searched people with a checkbox each.*

[Here's a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8QnX.png)

_

When you check someone, the name is added as a span to the div where "To:" is. Deselecting removes the name. People can be searched via the search bar, updating the list.

My question is: **how can I simply add the names into the search bar, instead of having a separate div, moving the cursor to the right**.

Like what it is on Facebook's Messenger or Instagram - [check picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTBhP.png).

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: @Nimish I'm going to add a screenshot of what I have, one sec.

Comment: Post your code or working snippet not screenshot

Comment: @Nimish Added both, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Ion won't work in snippet @Nimish